# Printing string from InputStream on TextView from handler

Tags: java, android, textview, handler

I want my TextView LineHunt1 to update each time there is something on the InputStream, which is handled by mHandler after receiving MSG message. Correct data from the stream appear in logcat, but nothing displays on the TextView. I have tried many different approaches, but none worked.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL = 1;
protected static final int CONNECTION_FAILED = 0;
protected static final int DISCONNECTED = 2;
protected static final int MSG = 3;
public boolean connected=false;

static Handler mHandler;
Activity mActivity;
static String data="1";
String message="da4o";
static TextView LineHunt1;
SeekBar LRseek;
TextView LRprogress;

public BluetoothAdapter BTadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
ConnectThread connect;
ConnectedThread IOthread;
BluetoothDevice device;
BluetoothSocket socket;
String address = "20:13:06:14:02:72";

 float discrete=0; 
 float start=0; 
 float end=100; 
 float start_pos=50; 
 int start_position=50;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);



    mActivity = this;

    ImageView right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    ImageView left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left);
    ImageView up = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.up);
    ImageView down = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.down);

    LRseek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.LRseek);
    LRprogress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LRprogress);


mHandler = new Handler(){

        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            super.handleMessage(msg);



            switch(msg.what){

            case CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL:
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zariadenie pripojené", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 connected=true;
                 break;

            case CONNECTION_FAILED: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nepodarilo sa pripojiť" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 connected=false;
                 break;

            case DISCONNECTED: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zariadenie bolo odpojené", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 connected=false; 
                 break;

            case MSG: setData((String) msg.obj);
                 if(data.contains("[B")){break;}
                 else {

                     mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                LineHunt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LineHunt1);
                                LineHunt1.setText(data);
                            }
                        });

                     Log.d("INPUT",data);
                     }
                 break;
            }
        }
    };





    LRseek.setProgress(start_position);
    LRseek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() { 


        @Override 
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 

            LRseek.setProgress(50);
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean         fromUser) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            // To convert it as discrete value 

            String seekProgress = "" + LRseek.getProgress();
            LRprogress.setText(seekProgress);
            send("LR " + seekProgress);
        } 
    }); 






    right.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg, MotionEvent event)
        {   
            String string;
            TextView tRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tRight);
            string = arg.getTag().toString();
            switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                tRight.setText(string);
                send("r");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                tRight.setText("release");
                send("R");
                break;

            }
         return true;
        }



   });
     left.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg, MotionEvent event)
            {
                String string;
                TextView tLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tLeft);
                string = arg.getTag().toString();
                switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

                    tLeft.setText(string);
                    send("l");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    tLeft.setText("release");
                    send("L");
                    break;
                }
             return true;
            }



       });
     up.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg, MotionEvent event)
            {
                String string;
                TextView tUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tUp);
                string = arg.getTag().toString();
                switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

                    tUp.setText(string);
                    send("f");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    tUp.setText("release");
                    send("F");
                    break;
                }
             return true;
            }



       });
     down.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg, MotionEvent event)
            {
                String string;
                TextView tDown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDown);
                string = arg.getTag().toString();
                switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                    tDown.setText(string);
                    send("b");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    tDown.setText("release");
                    send("B");
                    break;
                }
             return true;
            }



       });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}





public void send(String st){
if(connected)IOthread.write(st);
}   


public void connect(View v)  {



if (!BTadapter.isEnabled()) {


Intent enableIntent = new
            Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableIntent);
        }

if(BTadapter.isEnabled()){

    if(connected){
       connect.cancel();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    if(!connected){                 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        device =  BTadapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        connect = new ConnectThread(device);
        IOthread = new ConnectedThread(connect.mmSocket);

        connect.run();
        //IOthread.run();

            }}



}

public void Irun(View v)
{
IOthread.start();

} 

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
    // because mmSocket is final
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    mmDevice = device;
    //Log.d("masaker",device.getUuids().toString());
    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
        tmp =  mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

    } catch (IOException e) {Log.d("lager","ta co"); }
    mmSocket = tmp;
}

public void run() {
    // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
    BTadapter.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception

        mmSocket.connect();

    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
        try {
            mmSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException closeException) { 

        }


        // mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTION_FAILED, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        return;
    }

    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
    //manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
}



/** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
        mHandler.obtainMessage(DISCONNECTED).sendToTarget();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {


 /*   private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;*/
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
InputStream mmInStream;
OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read();

                mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG, bytes, -1, buffer.toString()).sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


 public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

 public void write(String  strings) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(strings.getBytes());
            Log.d("", strings);
        } catch (IOException e) { Log.d("ERR_OUT", "FEJL");}
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right TextView? You can use HierarchyViewer to check.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about this one, I even tried replacing it by a new one, but it didn't help.